# RDS closing connection too soon

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm trying to use AWS RDS databases, with external access, but from any application that I access it the connection closes too soon, and it looks like it is some property in RDS.
I tried to connect to MySQL and Postgres databases from a Spring Boot application and DBeaver and everything works fine but, in all cases, the connection stays active for like 1 minute, that is, if the connection stays idle RDS closes it.
I really believe that this is an RDS config, but I didn't fount anything...

Answer (score 3):

You can have a look at Parameter group. More info here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.html

You will be able to modify the default configuration value of your database and setup the correct "connection timeout" for your use case.

Comment: can i disable it? im attempting to migrate everything from one database to another and the connection will need to be open for hours if not a day or more. i know just use pgsql and dump it but we're converting to sql server from postgres and have a tool helping with the changing syntax that needs an open connection while it does its thing

Comment: You cannot completely disable it but you can set 31536000 as timeout (1 year). Or use 1 dump file per table